# Получение данных из базы MySQL при помощи RedBean

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp, steam

Помогите сделать сравнение данных с данными в базе MySQL. У меня есть SteamID пользователя, который нужно занести в базу данных при помощи ORM RedBean, но если запись с таким же SteamID уже есть, то её создавать не нужно. (Цель: Создать регистрацию на сайте через Steam.)

Comment: Ну раз запись с заданным SteamID должна присутствовать в единственном экземпляре, надо на это поле наложить в структуре требование уникальности. И выполнять вставку запросом `INSERT IGNORE SteamID, ... INTO ...`. Если вставляемое значение в таблице отсутствует - запись будет вставлена, если имеется - вставка будет проигнорирована без возникновения ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постарайтесь в случае вопроса указывать побольше информации, и части кода, которые Вы пробовали самостоятельно реализовать. Это не только помогает в разы ускорить ответ, но и даёт понять, что Вы действительно пытались разобраться с вопросом.
Так уж принято )

```
//Подключаем библиотеку
require 'rb.php';
// Подключаемся к БД.
R::setup( 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=redbean','login', 'password' ); 
// Проверяем соединение с БД.
if ( !R::testConnection() )
{
        exit ('Нет соединения с базой данных');
}
//Ищем, есть ли данные в базе с таким SteamID
$book = R::find('users', 'steamid LIKE ' . $profilesteamid);
// Получаем id записи (Это вдруг понадобится в логгировании, то будете знать какая запись была с таким SteamID)
$GetSteamID = key($book);
// Дальше обрабатываете данные (мало ли пустая запись, если id не обязательное поле в БД)

echo 'Запись уже существует';
print_r($GetSteamID);
if ($GetSteamID == "" or $GetSteamID == null){
//Если записи отсутствуют - то записываем данные в БД
    $book1 = R::dispense('users'); //передаем название таблицы users

    $book1['steamid'] = $profilesteamid;
    R::store($book1); // сохраняем объект $book в таблице
    echo 'запись произведена';
}
```

Comment: У меня в базе данных таблица называется users, там есть столбец steamid.

Comment: @4cher в чём сложность? Подставьте данные вместо указанных.

Comment: $users = R::findOne('users', 'steamid = ?', [$profilesteamid]);
   $GetSteamID = $users->steamid;
   if ($GetSteamID != "" or $GetSteamID != null){
     $users = R::dispense('users');
    $users->SteamID = $profilesteamid;
    R::store($users);
   } так?

Comment: $profilesteamid - steamid, полученный с формы регистрации

Comment: @4cher Почти. 
$users-> steamid = $profilesteamid

Comment: не получается, вообще никак

Comment: users - таблица бд, steamid - столбец таблицы users, переменная $profilesteamid - SteamID, полученный из формы. Как это сделать?

Comment: Изменил ответ в соответствии с Вашими данными. (Протестировано)